# Trying to deploy Confluence on Glassfish 4

Tags: java, glassfish, application-server, confluence

So I'm trying to deploy Confluence as a WAR on Glassfish 4 (Using Oracle JDK 7). The WAR deploys just fine except I get the following errors when trying to load the page in my browser:

```
Could not load bootstrap from environment
No server id found.
NoSuchMethodError:com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder.maximumSize(I)Lcom/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder;
```

Any thoughts as to what could cause this?

Comment: They seem to have slimmed down their supported app servers to just Tomcat.  Might be stuck using that.